# What is Kiosk Type Session? How to have it? How to use it?

Tags: 11.10, kiosk

I recently heard about Kiosk type Session for Ubuntu 11.10, How do i Use/Install it? What actually is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kiosk mode stands for a machine with very restricted acting ability. Often it is used to allow quick internet access for user of the machine, but not much more.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/) is an instruction for Setting up a Ubuntu 10.04 Internet Kiosk.

Another possibility would be to use [Gofris](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/07/install-gofris-on-ubuntu-1104-to.html) to reset the system settings after every reboot.

Comment: does that work for 11.10?

Comment: I'm quite sure that Gofris is working. From what I've read the instructions for setting up the Kiosk machine should be transferable to 11.10

Comment: i cant use gofris, thats not what i need